# "More to the West" in Red Rackham's Treasure. Why not "More to the East"?

Tags: tintin

In "Red Rackham's Treasure", the shipwreck location is `20°37'42.0" N 68°52'15.0" W`, which means it is [somewhere in the Caribbean](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/20%C2%B037'42.0%22N+68%C2%B052'15.0%22W/@20.8781421,-70.3697789,6.5z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d20.6283333!4d-68.8708333).

The treasure is in Marlinspike Hall, somewhere in Belgium, approximately 7000km to the East.

Professor Calculus is supposed to be clever enough to build a submarine or a nuclear powered rocket. Yet he keeps on saying that the treasure is "more to the West". Why?

Comment: If you go west far enough, you'll go right round...

Comment: He did sail eastward back to Europe on the Sirius.

Comment: If you're interested in comics, you might want to follow and support the new [Comics Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94426/comics-cartoons-animation) over on Area 51.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's because he's a crackpot. He says West but he means East. That's quite literally the joke.

Comment: He did build a rocket. So he must be clever and be able able to express himself clearly to lead a team for a huge project.

Comment: @EricDuminil While the good professor has his moments of clarity, you must admit that he also can be very, very dense. As far as I recall from the book (although it's been a long time since I read it; I may be misremembering), he based his conviction of "more to the west" on the swing of a pendulum.

Comment: @MrLister : you're totally right with the pendulum. It even seems to lead him to the treasure room, separately from Tintin's investigation. The professor is half-deaf and it often looks as if he didn't understand something, but he merely didn't hear it correctly.